Disable/enable control in X11/xlib
I am working on linux with xlib and am unclear on how to disable a control. This is a common pattern in GUI development where you enable/disable controls on a window based on certain conditions.
I've looked high and low and have not found a single example of such and am wondering if this is even possible in X11?
This seems strange because it's trivial elsewhere. For example using the Windows API:
EnableWindow(handle, bool)
IsWindowEnabled(handle)

and in Winforms:
Control.Enabled = true/false

Any help is much appreciated.

Basic X11 does not have the concept of "controls" at all.  Just windows.  X is a very low-level library.  You are probably using some add-on library that provides controls or widgets.  That's where you'll find enable and disable.

X11 does not have the concept of "controls" at all.  If you want to disable a window, you can use XSelectInput(display, win, 0) to "disable", use XSelectInput(display, win, control_mask) to "enable".

wms will override this about all of the time
